# Docker mailserver

Tags: docker, email, nginx, mail-server

I have a webserver running my application in docker containers. Actually, the structure is:

- container with app
- container with MySQL
- container with Nginx

The app and MySQL container are connected to the Nginx container which is the only one exposed to the network.
I would like to add a further container with a mailserver where to create some mailboxes with the same domain associated to the app.

Any suggestion about how to do that? I have found several guides, but each supposes an alone installation.

Comment: Yes take a look here : https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver

Comment: Thanks, I've already looked at it, however it does not seems to allow to integrate it into an existing docker-composer environment